# Evaluating $\;\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-} } \frac{e^{1/(x^2 -1)}}{x-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Consider the limit
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}  } \frac{e^{1/(x^2 -1)}}{x-1}$$

I tried to apply the L'Hospital rule. But  don't work. It complicates the computations. I also tried to solve the exercise without L'Hospital. But I am getting anywhere. Could someone help me with the exercise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: L'Hopital won't help you solve here, but it "works" in that $f'(x)/g'(x)$ converges to the same value as $f(x)/g(x).$ L'Hopital isn't guaranteed to help you solve limits. It can sometimes be used for that purpose, though.

Comment: The denominator tends to 0 as the numerator tends to $\infty$. In order to L’Hôpital to apply, the fraction has to be rewritten so that it tends to [0/0].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My strategy is to simplify expressions as much as possible before attacking the problem.

We have
$$\frac{e^{1/(x^2 -1)}}{x-1}=
\frac{e^{1/(x^2 -1)}}{x^2-1}(x+1)$$
The factor $x+1$ tends to $2.$ It suffices to examine the first ratio.

Let $t=(1-x^2)^{-1}.$ Then $x\to 1^{-}$ implies $t\to \infty.$ We have
$$\frac{e^{1/(x^2-1)}}{x^2-1}=-te^{-t}$$ Next  $$\lim_{t\to\infty}{t\over e^t}=0\quad (*)$$ Hence the final answer is $0.$

**Remark** Basing on $e^t\ge 1+t>t$ we get $$e^t=(e^{t/2})^2> {t^2\over 4}$$ This can be used for getting $(*)$ avoiding de l'Hôpital rule.

Answer (score 4):

Write $f(x) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}}{x - 1}$. Two easy things that anyone can do when confronted by a problem like this are

1. Plot the function $f(x)$.
2. Plug in some specific values of $x$, say $f(0.9)$ and $f(0.99)$.

A plot makes it clear that the limit is $0$:

[image]

While plugging in specific values gives $f(0.9) = -0.052 \dots$ and $f(0.99) = -1.5 \times 10^{-23}$, so we see that in fact $f$ approaches $0$ *very rapidly* as $x \to 1^{-}$.

Thinking a bit about the functional form of $f(x)$, it's not hard to see why: as $x \to 1^{-}$ we have $\frac{1}{x^2 - 1} \to - \infty$ so $e^{\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}} \to 0$ very rapidly, much faster than $x - 1$ does, and in fact much faster than any power of $x - 1$ does.

To actually prove it I think it's a little simpler to take the logarithm of $- f(x)$. So, we want to show that

$$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \ln (-f(x)) = \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \left( \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} - \log (1 - x) \right) = - \infty.$$

To see this, note that for $x \in (0, 1]$ we have $x + 1 \ge 1$ which gives $\frac{1}{x^2 - 1} = \frac{1}{(x - 1)(x + 1)} \le \frac{1}{x - 1}$, so an upper bound for the above is

$$\ln (-f(x)) \le \frac{1}{x - 1} - \log (1 - x) = - \left( \frac{1}{1 - x} - \log \frac{1}{1 - x} \right).$$

This suggests the substitution $u = \log \frac{1}{1 - x}$. As $x \to 1^{-}$ we have $u \to \infty$, and the above upper bound becomes $- (e^u - u)$, so we've reduced to showing that

$$\lim_{u \to \infty} (e^u - u) = \infty.$$

This is easy enough to just prove directly and I encourage you to just try it directly from the definition. You can use, for example, the inequality $e^u \ge 1 + u + \frac{u^2}{2}$.